# Как преобразовать строку в список и пройтись по нему, с помощью цикла for?

Tags: python

как преобразовать строку:
a='qwerty'

в список :
[q , w, e, r, t, y]

Comment: Какой тип у элементов списка?

Answer (score 4):

вот так:

```
res = list(a)
```

а чтобы пройтись по нему через цикл for, то с ним ничего делать не надо

```
for el in a:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

способ 1:

```
text = 'qwerty'
arr = [*text]

for l in arr:
```

способ 2:

```
text = 'qwerty'
arr = list(text)

for l in arr:
```

способ 3:

если надо просто пройтись:

```
text = 'qwerty'

for l in text:
```